# Implicit declaration in msm_performance.c

Tags: android, c++, c

I'm trying to compile a 64 Bit kernel for ZTE Blad S6 (msm8939) but I keep running into "implicit declaration" error.
I have tried the '-Wno-error' and have tried to remove 'Werror' from 'CFLAGS' & 'CPPFLAGS' but they weren't in the code at all!
I have Lubuntu 15.04 x64 & GCC 4.8
[This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_yu_msm8916/cm-12.0/drivers/soc/qcom/msm_performance.c) is the repo I'm using.

```
nonta72@HaswellGT2:~/kernel$ make ARCH=arm64 o=out Image -w
make: Entering directory '/home/nonta72/kernel'
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
  GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CHK     kernel/config_data.h
  CC      drivers/soc/qcom/msm_performance.o
drivers/soc/qcom/msm_performance.c: In function 'set_cpu_min_freq':
drivers/soc/qcom/msm_performance.c:271:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'cpufreq_get_policy' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if (cpufreq_get_policy(&policy, i))
   ^
drivers/soc/qcom/msm_performance.c:275:4: error: implicit declaration of function 'cpufreq_update_policy' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    ret = cpufreq_update_policy(i);
    ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target 'drivers/soc/qcom/msm_performance.o' failed
make[3]: *** [drivers/soc/qcom/msm_performance.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'drivers/soc/qcom' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers/soc/qcom] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'drivers/soc' failed
make[1]: *** [drivers/soc] Error 2
Makefile:815: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/nonta72/kernel'
nonta72@HaswellGT2:~/kernel$
```